# Sorting nested arrays via an Element in each Sub Array

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

Assuming I have something coming back from a JSON request that essentially looks like this --

```
$data = array('0'=> array('name' => 'Dr. Smith',
                          'address' => '3002 Fake Ave.',
                          'lat' => '34.711158',
                          'lng' => '-137.803578',
                          'phone' => '714.939.1324'),
              '1' => array('name' => 'Dr. Paul',
                           'address' => '801 Fake St.',
                           'lat' => '31.749917',
                           'lng' => '-137.834388'));
```

How do I order it by one of the elements? Say if I wanted to sort the whole array of arrays by the `Lat` element? And put it back in the `$data` element, so I can keep working with it.

I've read the stuff on PHP about [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and sorting by a sub-array element, but when I try to work with their code examples they aren't working.

Comment: To make the question sound less confusing, try calling them nested arrays. Just a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The callback function for usort will receive two of your array entries (which are arrays in themselves) and must answer whether $a comes before or after $b.

For example the function would receive

```
  $a = array('Lat' => 45, 'Name' => 'Mickey Mouse', ...)
  $b = array('Lat' => 47, ...)
```

So if you want to sort by Lat element, you would use,

```
  function sort_by_lat($a, $b)
  {
      return $a['Lat'] - $b['Lat']; // or b - a to sort the other way
  }

  usort($array, "sort_by_lat");
```

A problem you might have is that this way, if you sorted by longitude, you might consider -1 to be less than +1, and -179 to be less than +180. Which might or might not be what you expect. In this case you would need to use if(), and/or introduce some conversion.

To sort by name, you can do

```
 if ($a['field'] > $b['field']) return 1;
 if ($a['field'] == $b['field']) return 0;
 return -1;
```

(again invert +1 and -1 to get sorted the other way).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget all your data is coming in as strings, so you need to convert the number values to floats to do a proper comparison.

http://codepad.org/p2EMfTDR

```
$data = array('0'=> array('name' => 'Dr. Smith', 'address' => '3002 Fake Ave.', 'lat' => '20.711158', 'lng' => '10.803578', 'phone' => '714.939.1324'), '1' => array('name' => 'Dr. Paul', 'address' => '801 Fake St.', 'lat' => '10.749917', 'lng' => '20.834388'));

function cmpLat($a, $b)
{
    if(floatval($a['lat']) > floatval($b['lat'])) {
        return 1;
    } elseif(floatval($a['lat']) < floatval($b['lat'])) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

function cmpLng($a, $b)
{
    if(floatval($a['lng']) > floatval($b['lng'])) {
        return 1;
    } elseif(floatval($a['lng']) < floatval($b['lng'])) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

usort($data, "cmpLat");

print_r($data);

usort($data, "cmpLng");

print_r($data);
```